# Handling global settings node in MVC partial views on Umbraco site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I'm currently setting up my partial views on my master template, like so:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;

    IPublishedContent global = Umbraco.TypedContentSingleAtXPath("//*[@nodeTypeAlias='Global']");
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        @Html.Partial("Header", global)

        @RenderBody()

        @Html.Partial("Footer", global)
    </body>
</html>
```

The global node being called contains everything needed for the header and footer to work, namely content-managed logos and navigation. As things stand, this works fine.

However, it feels wasteful to have to declare and pass this global node every time I want to grab global settings. My background is with WebForms so while I could just create a class and call this each time to grab the node I'd like to know of a MVC-type way of handling this.

Does anyone know of a clean way I can merge this declaration into a Model or Controller, so that I can call global settings when needed, without having to declare first and call into my partial views?

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use a singleton/statoc object which gets initialized during bootstrapping/global.asax.

Then you should be able to access it from wherever you want...

:edit:
To give you an example:

Create a class which provides static properties

```
public class Global
{
    public static string SomeProperty { get; private set; }

    internal static void Initialize()
    {
        // do initialize your global properties
        SomeProperty = "Something";
    }
}
```

Initialize it during global asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Global.Initialize();
}
```

Use it in your views:

```
@Global.SomeProperty
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is there any chance you could provide a code example of how I'd call this in my partial view from the global.asax file?

Comment: Sure, I added some very basic example

Comment: Sadly, The TypedContentSingleAtXPath() method provided by UmbracoHelper is context based (see http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/45990-Instantiating-UmbracoHelper-in-Static-Class-Library). If I try and use it in the Global.asax file then it does not find the correct node.

Comment: The answer to the question you posted already contains a good solution for you. You could simply create extension methods for the UmbracoHelper which handle your custom needs.